# Bootstrap 5 responsive carousel text problems

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm building a new website, I'm using bootstrap 5. i have added a responsive carousel to the header field, but the text and button in the carousel are not compatible. I am adding a few images and source code to better understand the problem.

```
    <!-- Carousel -->
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Indicators/dots -->
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="3"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="4"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images/slider/5.png" alt="Los Angeles" class="d-block img-fluid" style="width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>BİZİ ARAMAKTAN ÇEKİNMEYİN</h3>
                <p>Teknik Destek Hizmetleri</p>
                <p>+90 850 111 11 11</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Detaylı Bilgi</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/slider/1.png" alt="" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Yakınınızda bir <span style="color:#0597d4;">3CX</span> Distribütörü arıyorsanız, doğru
                    yerdesiniz.</h3><br />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Detaylı Bilgi</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/slider/7.png" alt="" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Fortinet BİLİŞİM</h3>
                <p><span style="color: red; ">FORTİNET TÜRKİYENİN</span> SELECT PARTNERİ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="special" class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/slider/12.png" alt="" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Sektör tecrübemizi yeni neslin çalışma koşulları ile
                    birleştirerek,</h3>
                <p>kurumların iç dinamiklerine özel avantajlı
                    çözüm üretme vizyonundan yola çıktık.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/slider/15.png" alt="" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Fortinet olarak, yerel alan ağı, uzak ağ, kablosuz ağ, ağ güvenliği ve güvenli uzaktan erişim gibi
                </h3>
                <p>ağ teknolojilerinin kurulumu ve devreye alınması gibi ağ çözümlerini sunuyoruz.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel -->
```

CSS code

```
 .carousel-caption{
transform: translateY(-50%) ;
bottom: initial;
top: 50%;
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAAi6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUJDf.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to add `d-flex` class to the `carousel-caption`, also add `align-items-center`

```
<div class="carousel-caption align-items-center d-flex">
  <h3>BİZİ ARAMAKTAN ÇEKİNMEYİN</h3>
  <p>Teknik Destek Hizmetleri</p>
  <p>+90 850 111 11 11</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Detaylı Bilgi</button>
</div>
```